# Bazel sorts keys of attr.label_keyed_string_dict implicity

Tags: bazel, attr, skylark

I'm currently running Bazel 0.9.0. I've defined a custom Bazel rule. In one of the fields, I'm using a *attr.label_keyed_string_dict*. While processing the keys during evaluation phase, the keys are being sorted implicitly. Is there any flag/option to disable this feature. I've checked version 0.14 in which the keys aren't sorted implicitly. But I wanted to know if there is anything we can do within version 0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything you can do for this in `0.9.0`. Please update to the newest version of Bazel :) Are there issues preventing you from updating?